# Select multiple file types in powershell. Version 2

Tags: powershell

I am trying to select files that have identical names except for the extenstion...

IE:

```
idiotCode.dll, idiotCode.pdb, idiotCode.xml, StupidFool.dll, StupidFool.pdb, StupidFool.xml
```

et cetera.

take a gander at my where-Object call in the below script line...

```
gci -path $FromPath | ? {$_.Name -match "idiotCode|StupidFool|YourAnIdiot|TheSuckIstHeMatterWhichU" -and $_.Name -like "*.dll"} | foreach{write-host("Do I have the files here? : "+ $_.Fullname + " -destination" + $ToPath) }
```

Can I use the like parameter to do that?  Is there another way to do that?  Maybe something in my get-childItem method call which I could pipe into my Where-Object call?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot that you can do with just the `Get-ChildItem` Cmdlet. If you look at the help [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849800.aspx), you can do a lot of the filtering there. Specifically using the filters `-Filter`, `-Include` and `-Exclude`

For ex:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $FromPath -Include "idiotCode.*","StupidFool.*","YourAnIdiot.*","TheSuckIstHeMatterWhichU.*" -Filter "*.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm a little confused as to the whole concept here because you say you want to select multiple files of the same name but different extensions. Then you pull a directory listing of PathA, filter out everything except files in a kind of "approved names list", and only allow .DLL files to show, and then reference PathB for reasons unknown.
I'm guessing here, but I think you want to query .DLL files from PathA, and then check for matching files from PathB.

```
$Reference = (GCI $FromPath -Filter "*.DLL").basename
GCI $ToPath|?{$_.BaseName -Match $Reference}|FT -Group BaseName
```